# Export ipa file fails

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, rvm, ipa

Using Xcode v11.3 I try to export my .IPA file and get this error.

> An error occurred during export. The data couldn’t be read because of it
>   isn’t in the correct format

This is shown in IDEDistribution.standard.log

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- cfpropertylist (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:15:in `<main>'
2020-02-05 07:57:11 +0000  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool exited with 1
2020-02-05 07:57:11 +0000  ipatool JSON: (null)
```

I have tried rvm use system but in vain. Thanking in anticipation.

Answer (score 13):

**TL;DR**

Running:

```sh
$ gem install CFPropertyList
$ gem install sqlite3
```

and then **restarting** solved it for me.

---

**Full story:**

I've just had the same problem. Googling around I found [this article](https://egeek.me/2018/04/14/ipa-export-error-in-xcode-and-ruby/) which talks about a different problem, but pointed me to the right direction: there is an issue with Ruby.

I then bumped into [this issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6382) which focused on the `cannot load such file -- cfpropertylist` part of the error message.

Running `gem install CFPropertyList` effectively allowed me to move forward one more step. This time a similar error complained about `sqlite3`. Running `gem install sqlite3`, again, should solve the problem.

Please note that you need SQLite installed systemwide (`brew install sqlite`), and that you NEED to restart your system, for whatever reason.

Comment: Thank you @mjsarfatti ! I've got the same issue with sqlite3 and it has been solved with your advice!

`/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3 (LoadError)`

Comment: After running these commands, I restarted Xcode and that solved the issue

Comment: Still facing the issue. Using M1 mac.

Comment: If this doesn't work, try opening Xcode with Rosetta it solved my problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. `gem install sqlite3` was my issue as per the XCode logs. No idea why it would require that when everything was working a day prior.

Comment: Who are struggling with M1 macs, running in Terminal `gem install sqlite3 --platform arm64-darwin` instead of just `gem install sqlite3` has worked for me

Comment: @DmitriiKlassneckii That worked for me. I'm on a M1 Mac. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

to fix it on M1 Mac

Go to Xcode foldar > right click open Get Info > make sure open using Rosetta has been checked

don't forget quit Xcode then open it

Answer (score 0):

Another reason this can occur is that you're using a beta or release candidate of Xcode that is not approved for App Store submission.

To fix, upgrade (or downgrade) Xcode to a version that is approved for App Store submission.